# Assert the record is deleted

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I'm using webdriver with testng java..

1) Is there any way to assert if the deleted record is not present on page anymore. If yes, please give me a small sample code.

Thanks

---

Thanks for the replies. Currently, I'm not following page object pattern..What I do is:

I just create @Test methods and write my code inside them..Example:

@Test (Priority= 0...)
//code

@Test (Priority= 1...)
//code

and so on..

As for delete, when I create a new user, the record adds to the existing records. Each record has checkbox with it which has particualar xpath. The problem is that the xpath is always the same for the top most record, so to assert if the new record is deleted is not possible.

@Gavin: your 'Wait' technique seems good.

xpath for topmost record's chechbox = .//*[@id='main']/div/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/input

xpath for second topmost record's chechbox = .//*[@id='main']/div/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/input

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about asserting the test in another manner?

For example assert that the correct records are still present?

Try asking WebDriver to wait for the presents of something unique to that records, and when the wait for x to be present times out catch the WebDriver exception, and then you know the item isint there. 
Its a bit of a hack to my mind.

Is this something you should be testing at the presentation layer?  I would test this as a straight unit test sending the delete request to the "endpoint" and then asserting the contents of the returned resultset/lsit

Comment: Apparently I cant comment yet.  Not enough reputation.

Comment: Varun's answer is the same as what I was saying, he just showed the code.
You dont have to follow the page model, I personally feel it has its limitation, but thats a different story.
Option 1:
Given that it is a list of users, with checkboxes, you dont have to assert that the user was deleted, just that three users werent deleted.
If you have user A, B, C & D and delete C, your grid should only have three entries of A, B & D.
Option 2:
Try having your users added to the grid in a div with an id, then you can use By (as per Varun example) with the id

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a By object of the said record you can have a method isElementPresent() implemented in your code which will return you true or false based on the condition whether the said element is present or not.

```
public boolean isElementPresent(WebDriver driver, By by){
   try{
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
   }catch(NoSuchElementException e){
     return false;
   }
}
```